# @NoSqlOneToMany doesn't work in PlayORM

Tags: playorm

I have created a simple example of play orm application basing on the standard example.

You can download the source here http://yadi.sk/d/FksgPpsXBqRPb.

The example must be run with Play 2.2.0 framework.

You can test it with Rest Client for Firefox.

***1. Create a Man:***

```
http://localhost:9000/saveMan
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Petro",
    "age": 30
}
```

in the output you will get the Main Id

***2. Create a Car associated with the Man***

```
http://localhost:9000/saveCar
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "model": "Aveo",
    "man": {"id": "<Man Id>"}
}
```

***3. Get the man***

```
http://localhost:9000/getMan/<Man Id>
Method: GET
```

***The result:***

```
{

      "id": "<Man Id>",
      "name": "Petro",
      "age": 30,
      "cars":
      [
      ]
}
```

**As you see the cars are not retrieved though I use @NoSqlOneToMany annotation.**

Answer (score 0):

do you have any source in github?  That is quite a large file and all the code you show in the post is json stuff.  Are you using mongodb or cassandra?

The "cars" I would have thought would have listed the FK's in this case or if you use @NoSqlEmbedded, it would list the whole car in each entry of the car list.

If you are using mongodb, vikas, will know more than me.  Let us know what database backend you are using and if you can throw some actual source code on the page, that would be nice too.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: The same result both with PlayORM in-memory database and with Cassandra 1.1.6. All the source code is in this archive http://yadi.sk/d/FksgPpsXBqRPb. This is fully working project with all needed dependencies. Is it 7 Mb much for you to download?

Comment: Try this first to make sure all tests are passing on that cassandra.  In addition to the test here http://buffalosw.com/wiki/getting-started-with-the-in-memory-nosql-database-for-testing-example-4/ modify FactorySingleton.java from serverType = DbTypeEnum.IN_MEMORY; to serverType = DbTypeEnum.CASSANDRA; and run all the test suites....this has examples of OneToMany that you can compare with your stuff to see why yours is not working(if the test case fails though, let us know).